# It keeps saying ActiveX component can't create object: 'Shell.LocalMachine'

Tags: vbscript, activex

When I run the code, I get an error saying

ActiveX component can't create object: 'Shell.LocalMachine'

```
Class MachineName
    Private internal_ComputerName

    Public Function SetMachineName
        Set objComputer = CreateObject("Shell.LocalMachine")
        internal_ComputerName = objComputer.MachineName
    End Function

    Public Property Get GetMachineName
        GetMachineName = internal_ComputerName
    End Property
End Class

Dim objMachine
Set objMachine = New MachineName
objMachine.SetMachineName
```

Comment: is "Shell.LocalMachine" installed? search your registry with regedit

Comment: Must admit I hadn't come across that object before. I'd normally create a ["WScript.Network"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6wt333f%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object and get the ComputerName property. If you're diagnosing "Shell.LocalMachine" I can tell you that on my copy of XP it is provided by system32\shgina.dll

Comment: See also [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_network_names_computer.php) for a lot more info.

Comment: which version of windows are you running?

Comment: judging by [this thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/205313/481135.aspx) it's on XP only

Comment: Morbo - can you please answer the question so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morbo said "Must admit I hadn't come across that object before. I'd normally create a "WScript.Network" object and get the ComputerName property. If you're diagnosing "Shell.LocalMachine" I can tell you that on my copy of XP it is provided by system32\shgina.dll"

Answer (score 1):

thanks for this.  I am having the same problems when using this `Shell.Localmachine` on my windows 7 64 bit machine when i try to run a simple vbscript code. I had to default to `WScript.Network` instead:

```
'just a test script
'set objComputer = CreateObject("Shell.LocalMachine")

'wscript.echo "computer name" & objcomputer.machinename

Set objWshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
wscript.echo "computer name : " & objwshnet.computername
```